# Uncaught CURLEXCEPTION in facebook login - php sdk

Tags: facebook, exception, curl

Sometimes, especially, when I am not logged in Facebook, an error shows in my login page with the code pasted from the php-sdk. You can see the output at http://jnfp.tk/login.php. When I refresh the page, sometimes the error goes and the correct output shows but sometimes, the following error shows up :-

Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 7: Failed to connect to 2a03:2880:10:cf01:face:b00c:0:4: Network is unreachable thrown in /home/vhosts/www.jnfp.tk/src/base_facebook.php on line 977.

Please tell me how to fix it...

Comment: Yes! I changed my server and now, everything seems to be normal...Facebook login ph sdk is awesome...! - @themhz

Comment: I was using localhost, but there were reports by others having the same issue